# Phyton3 error >> global name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know why I am having this error. Please enlighten me. Here's my code:
filename: sqlfunc.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
class SQL:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection_string = ''
        self.sql = ''

    def exec_nonquery(connection_string, sql):
        self.connection_string = connection_string
        self.sql = sql
        self.__connection = self.__mydb(self.connection_string)
        self.__transaction = self.__connection.begin()
        try:
            self.__connection.execute(self.sql).fetchall()
            self.__transaction.commit()
        except:
            self.__transaction.rollback()
            raise
        _connection.close()

    def exec_query(self, connection_string, sql):
        self.connection_string = connection_string
        self.sql = sql
        self.__connection = self.__mydb(self.connection_string)
        self.__result = None
        self.query_result = []
        try:
            self.__result = self.__connection.execute(sql)
            self.query_result = list(self.__result)
        except:
            raise
        self.__connection.close()
        return self.query_result
```

Now, I tried:

```
from sqlfunc import SQL
SQL.exec_nonquery('mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger@mydsn','select * from table1')
```

and I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "./sqlfunc.py", line 25, in exec_nonquery
    self.connection_string = connection_string
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

Is there anything I did wrong or missing?

I changed exec_nonquery to

```
def exec_nonquery(self, connection_string, sql)
```

But it leads me to this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: exec_nonquery() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sql'
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here, use `SQL.exec_nonquery()` as a class method? You don't have a `self` argument to the method, nor will you have one as there is no *instance* to bind to.

Comment: What, if anything, do you expect to happen here? Why not create a `SQL()` *instance*, have it handle the connection string and call `exec_nonquery)` on that *without passing in the connection string again*? You appear to not yet understand how classes and instances work.

Comment: Yes, that's why I am trying to understand through here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"Is there anything I did wrong or missing?"* - yes, you failed to include `self` as the first positional argument to your method:

```
def exec_nonquery(connection_string, sql):
```

should be

```
def exec_nonquery(self, connection_string, sql):
                # ^ see here
```

You are also trying to call this instance method on the class. The minimal fix is:

```
sql = SQL() # create instance
sql.exec_nonquery('mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger@mydsn',
                  'select * from table1') # call method
```

but as Martijn points out you really should refactor the class to make the most of OOP.

Comment: It's being used as a class method.

Comment: i tried it. please see edited. but new error occurs.

Comment: @MartijnPieters then it should be `cls` instead of `self` and decorated `@classmethod` but the answer is the same

Comment: @jonrsharpe: exactly, the OP seems to want to set instance attributes as well though. There is a huge conceptual understanding disconnect here.

Comment: @KrisEdison that's because you're trying to call an *instance method* on the *class*.

Comment: I got it. Thanks @jonrsharpe. I am really new in OOP. Thanks for the understanding.